# Spyder console does not show the variable shape

Tags: python, spyder

My code run perfectly in spyder and provides me all the shapes correctly when the print command is used in the code to display it. However, when I type variable.shape in the spyder console, it give me NameError: name 'variable' is not defined. What could be the issue?

The following is the screenshot with the specific variable name:

[image]

As you can see, the output gives me the shape of X_train1 as (219,99,15) but when asked specifically about X_train1.shape, it gives me an error.

Comment: the issue is that the variable is not defined in whatever python process the console is running

Comment: How do I solve this?